# Do all Samsung devices sold in India after 2014 have e-fuse built-in? When was Samsung e-fuse Knox introduced?

Tags: samsung-knox

I have Samsung J7 Prime bought in 2017 and Samsung J2 bought in 2016. How can I know if it has e-fuse Knox security built-in? I searched a lot but did not find any answers specifically for the Indian market.

Do all Samsung devices from 2015 have Samsung Knox Security e-fuse hardware built-in?

Comment: As far as I understand the e-fuse is an integral part of Knox, hence if your devices are on the Knox list they should have an e-fuse https://www.samsungknox.com/en/knox-platform/supported-devices

Comment: My device is in the list you given.Software support may be installed later in any devices. But i can not figure out whether E-FUSE is there in my mobile or not? Is there any way to figure out it?